# Not Equals Constraint in PROC OPTMODEL

Tags: sas

I have an optimization problem that I need to solve. It's a binary linear programming problem, so all of the decision variables are equal to 0 or 1. I need certain combinations of these decision variables to add up to either 0 or 2+, they cannot sum to 1. I'm struggling with how to accomplish this in `PROC OPTMODEL`.

Something like this is what I need:

```
con sum_con: x+y+z~=1;
```

Unfortunately, this just throws a syntax error... Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below for a linear reformulation. However, you may not need it. In SAS 9.4m2 (SAS/OR 13.2), your expression works as written. You just need to invoke the (experimental) CLP solver:

```
proc optmodel;
/* In SAS/OR 13.2 you can use your code directly.
   Just invoke the experimental CLP solver */
    var x binary, y binary, z binary;
    con sum_con: x+y+z~=1;
    solve with clp / findall;
    print {i in 1 .. _NSOL_} x.sol[i] 
          {i in 1 .. _NSOL_} y.sol[i]
          {i in 1 .. _NSOL_} z.sol[i];
```

produces immediately:

```
[1] x.SOL y.SOL z.SOL 
  1     0     0     0 
  2     0     1     1 
  3     1     0     1 
  4     1     1     0 
  5     1     1     1
```

In older versions of SAS/OR, you can still call PROC CLP directly,
which is not experimental. 
The syntax for your example will be very similar to PROC OPTMODEL's.

I am sure, however, that your model has other variables and constraints.
In that case, remember that no matter how you formulate this,
it is still a search space with a hole in the middle. 
So it potentially can make the solver perform poorly.
How poorly is hard to predict. It depends on other features of your model.

If MILP is a better fit for the rest of your model,
you can reformulate your constraint as a valid MILP in two steps.
First, add a binary variable that is zero only when the expression is zero:

```
/* If solve with CLP is not available, you can linearize the disjunction: */
var IsGTZero binary; /* 1 if any variable in the expression is 1 */
con IsGTZeroBoundsExpression: 3 * IsGTZero >= x + y + z;
```

Then add another constraint that forces the expression to be 
at least the constant you want (in this case 2) when it is nonzero.

```
num atLeast init 2;
con ZeroOrAtLeast: x + y + z >= atLeast * IsGTZero;
min f=0; /* Explicit objectives are unnecessary in 13.2 */
solve;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Unfortunately, I have SAS/OR 13.1, so the CLP solver won't work. However, I had already decided to use the second solution you suggest several days ago. I didn't really want to be that drastic... but, hey, it works.

Answer (score 2):

The following equation should work:

```
(x+y-z)*z + (y+z-x)*x + (x+z-y)*y > -1
```

It can be generalized to more than three variables and if you have some large number you should be able to use index expansions to make it easier.

Comment: Fascinating... very different from the solution I ended up going with, but that's some mathematical wizardry I never would have come up with on my own...